# TextEditor + .vertical Axis on TextField Disables .focused Modifier macOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, macos-sonoma

I have a SwiftUI app that runs on both iOS and macOS. We utilize the `.focused` modifier to determine what fields are currently active. After updating our machines to macOS 14 it seems like the `.focused` modifier is broken for TextFields that utilize a `.vertical` axis as well as for `TextEditor` Multiline text edit is critical for us, but now we're unable to save data entered. Is this a known issue with macOS 14 or somehow intentional?

Below is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @FocusState private var isEmailFocused: Bool
  @State private var email = ""

  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          Form {
            TextEditor(text: $email)
                  .focused($isEmailFocused)
          }
          .navigationTitle("Sign in")
          .onChange(of: isEmailFocused) { newValue in
              print(newValue)
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @FocusState private var isEmailFocused: Bool
  @State private var email = ""

  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          Form {
            TextField("Address", text: $email, axis: .vertical)
                  .focused($isEmailFocused)
          }
          .navigationTitle("Sign in")
          .onChange(of: isEmailFocused) { newValue in
              print(newValue)
          }
      }
  }
}
```

This functionality worked flawlessly in macOS 13.

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests, the print shows `isEmailFocused` = true.
On MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios17 devices (not Previews),
MacCatalyst and MacOS 14.1 app. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine works fine on iOS regardless, just MacOS where it doesn't. Haven't tried uploading to 14.1 yet...

Comment: as I mentioned, it works well for me on MacOS 14.1 app as well.